# JSTL sessionScope attribute is not working even after providing taglib in jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, session, jstl

I am creating a Demo Spring MVC application, and I am trying to maintain Session with Interceptor. Everything is working fine inflow, But when I am trying to get session object value on JSP page with JSTL **sessionScope** like this: **${sessionScope.LoginSession.firstName}** ,jsp page is not accepting it and it is printing this sessionScope line as it is, although i have added taglib and evrything properly.

I am getting session value correctly when I am trying to get value like this: session.getAttribute("LoginSession"), but it is not working with JSTL sessionScope.

My JSP page is:

```
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>Carwale Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div align="right">
        <%
            Object user = session.getAttribute("LoginSession");
        System.out.println("Value from jsp "+user);
        %>
        <c:out value="${sessionScope.LoginSession.firstName}"></c:out>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${sessionScope.LoginSession!=null}">
                <c:out value="Welcome," />
                <a href="addProduct.do"> <c:out
                        value="${sessionScope.LoginSession.firstName}" />
                </a>
                <div align="right">
                    <a href="logout.do">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </c:when>
        </c:choose>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My web.xml file looks like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_3.xsd">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-dao.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

JSTL Dependency in POM:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am Expecting that it should give me session Value properly but in JSP Page sessionScope value is appearing as it was written: **${sessionScope.LoginSession.firstName}**

Comment: @BalusC sir, i have read that answer where someone suggested to remove <!DOCTYPE> from Web.xml but in my web.xml that  DOCTYPE was already removed. And still i am not getting result. Please help

Comment: Read the rest of the answer. You web.xml is still Servlet 2.3.